# Why is Xcode saying Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialised without an application ID

Tags: ios, xcode, sdk, admob

I have followed the exact instructions as given by the googleAdMob website however Xcode still complains that I have not added a GADApplication identifier to my info.plist. FYI- the application does build fine however it will crash as soon as it opens. The site I used: https://developers.google.com/ad-manager/mobile-ads-sdk/ios/quick-start#update_your_infoplist

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMYBD.jpg)

```
<dict>
        <key>GADApplicationIdentifier</key>
        <string>ca-app-pub-7134464775664257~1540277419</string>
        <key>SKAdNetworkItems</key>
        <array>
<dict>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove the `<dict>`...

Your `<key>GADApplicationIdentifier</key>` must be right under the `<key>UIAplicationScene`... something like that:

```
<dict>
<key>...
<key>UIAplicationSceneManifest</key>
<key>GADApplicationIdentifier</key>
<string>ca-app-pub-7134464775664257~1540277419</string>
<key>SKAdNetworkItems</key>
<array>..
</array>
</dict>
```